# Fullcalendar Displaying the end time of an event

Tags: fullcalendar

how do i display the end time of an even in fullcalendar? My event is triggered right, but there is no end time displayed
This is an example event. Did i miss something?

```
title:'WM 2010 - 03.06.2010 - 00:00',
description: 'Bei uns ist jeden Tag WM Party',
start: new Date(2010, 5,  3, 00, 5),
end: new Date(2010, 6,  3, 23, 6),
allDay: true
```

Answer (score 25):

The appropriate solution in the most recent version of fullCalendar is to use displayEventEnd.
This is because timeFormat afects more stuff.
displayEventEnd allows us to even specify the views where we want the end time to be shown.

```
displayEventEnd: {
                    month: false,
                    basicWeek: true,
                    "default": true
                }
```