# Display ending time in fullcalendar week view only

Tags: fullcalendar

Edit to add: Sorry, found the answer here:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat

```
timeFormat: { 
month: 'H:mm', 
'': 'H:mm-{H:mm}' 
},
```

end of edit

I'm using fullcalendar, and I want to include the ending time in the "week" and "day" views. I [found an answer by Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150371/fullcalendar-displaying-the-end-time-of-an-event) on how to display the ending time:

```
timeFormat:  'HH:mm { - HH:mm}'
```

Nico wrote:

> Blockquote the time between {} is the end time. If you don't specify the ending time between curly brackets it will just display the start time twice

How could I *only* show the end time in views other than the full month view? I would like the regular week view to have start and end time. (In month view, it just takes too much space.)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, found the answer here:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat

```
timeFormat: { 
month: 'H:mm', 
'': 'H:mm-{H:mm}' 
},
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

The above answer no longer works in the newest version of FullCalendar. The correct answer is the use the [displayEventEnd](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventEnd/) option for the view. Like this:

```
views: {
    week: {
        displayEventEnd: true
    }
}
```