# Add End Time for FullCalendar's Week and Daily View

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar v2 now and I found it is quite useful. However, I have encountered a problem when I want to show the end time of an event.

I want to show both start time and end time within a day in week and daily view like "09:00-17:00". I have found a solution in [Display ending time in fullcalendar week view only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237422/display-ending-time-in-fullcalendar-week-view-only) but it seems a v1 version. I use this in v2 and failed.

How can I show both start time and end time within a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here: [Fullcalendar event's end time is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936259/fullcalendar-events-end-time-is-missing) works for version 1.6.1. However, the formatDates function has been replaced by [formatRange](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatRange/) in v2. So, use

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, $el, view) {
        var formattedTime = $.fullCalendar.formatRange(event.start, event.end, "HH:mm");
        // If FullCalendar has removed the title div, then add the title to the time div like FullCalendar would do
        if($el.find(".fc-event-title").length === 0) {
            $el.find(".fc-event-time").text(formattedTime + " - " + event.title);
        }
        else {
            $el.find(".fc-event-time").text(formattedTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am stuck by this replaced function and this help me!

Answer (score 2):

I found that this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24951989/590382

---

In FullCalendar >= 2.0.1, there is a setting called `displayEventEnd`.

**Documentation:** http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventEnd/

> Whether or not to display an event's end time text when it is
>   rendered on the calendar.

**Example:**

```
displayEventEnd: {
    month: false,
    basicWeek: true,
    "default": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for such a convuluted answer as the one above.
I had the same issue and I fixed it by simply configure the fullcalendar properties as so:

```
timeFormat: {
            month: "HH:mm",
            week: "HH:mm",
            day: "HH:mm"
        },
```