# jQuery Full Calendar event title time is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a jQuery Full Calendar in my UI and it looks as follows:

[image]

The problem is the 10:00-10:00am portion of the event title, which seemingly is added to the element based upon the event startTime and endTime parameters in the JSON which sets up the UI element. Please see my code section for this here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
            },
            allDayText: 'All Day',
            columnFormat: {
                month: 'ddd',
                week: 'ddd d/M',
                day: 'dddd d/M'
            },
            editable: false,
            weekends: true,
            timeFormat: 'h:mm-h:mma ',
            axisFormat: 'hh:mma',
            firstDay: 1,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            defaultView: 'month',
            minTime: '10:00',
            maxTime: '17:00',
            monthNames: ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],
            monthNamesShort: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","nov","Dec"],
            dayNames: ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],
            dayNamesShort: ["Sun","Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thus", "Fri", "Sat"],
            buttonText: {
                today: "Today",
                day: "Day",
                week:"Week",
                month:"Month"
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: false,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {

            },

            events: [
                               {
                                        id: "3",
                                        title: "My event title",
                                        start: new Date(2014,10,03,10,0),
                                        end: new Date(2014,10,03,12,0),
                                        allDay: false,
                                        backgroundColor : "#7F97FF",
                                        textColor: "white"
                                    },
```

The problem is in the UI it shows 10:00-10:00am which doesnt make sense. According to my events code it should start at 10,00,00 and end at 12,00,00 so why doesnt the title match this? Can somebody please help me!

Comment: read [Event object docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/). you are supplying non standard date format to `start` and `end`

Comment: Seemingly this should work but has the same result:

 start: new moment(new Date(<?php echo $Y;?>,<?php echo $M;?>,<?php echo $D;?>,10,0)),
                                        end: new moment(new Date(<?php echo $Y;?>,<?php echo $M;?>,<?php echo $D;?>,12,0)),

Comment: No i am not - look closer. Start is 10 for hours, end is 12.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem. Can get plugin js and css from cdn resource

Comment: This is a replication of the problem....it shows the exact issue - try it!

Comment: if you want help it's on you to build the demo with data similar to yours. jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar Displaying the end time of an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150371/fullcalendar-displaying-the-end-time-of-an-event)

Comment: I have tried jsfiddle but cannot get the UI to display : http://jsfiddle.net/1fnf23fk/1/ Please take a look

Comment: @RenegadeAndy because you need to provide the external resources for FullCalendar. You can do the came using a Code Snippet here tho.

Comment: can you add that in, im not sure how using jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you! I have just realised I was using version 2 of the calendar and not V2.3 which is what your example uses here. It still doesnt work so I assume this must be a major part of the problem?

Comment: Upgrading to V2.0.1 of the plugin fixed the issue! yahoo!!!! Thanks for your help @MikeSmithDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FullCalendar is not configured correctly since you want the text "Start - End" Time on each event.

```
 timeFormat: 'h:mm-h:mma ', // the output i.e. "10:00-10:00pm"
 timeFormat: 'h:mma ',      // the output i.e. "10:00pm"

 displayEventEnd : true,    // it will show on all views (Start - End) in your timeFormat
```

I've updated your [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fnf23fk/2/), since you forgot to insert the external sources, I've imported the FullCalendar libraries in order to work.

Comment: Turns out I was using V2 of the calendar, V2.3 is significently different but using your fix doesnt work with V2 of the source. I grabbed V2.0.1 which I could just drop in - and your fix fixed the issue! Thank you!